# Where is Maven local repository?

Tags: maven

Where is Maven local repository?

I want to remove the code and force maven to check out the latest version of the build through "Maven Update".

I searched stackoverflow for "maven local" and did not find any straight forward answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, Maven local repository is an .m2 folder :

1. Unix/Mac OS X – ~/.m2
2. Windows – C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2

Comment: Shoudn't there be two more slashes - before and after "{your-username}"?

Comment: On Win10 default path is C:\Users\<username>\.m2

Answer (score 1):

The Maven local repository is located in the /home/.m2 directory, the folder is probably hidden. So, you'll need to press Ctrl+H to see hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

check your settings.xml. The one in the maven installation. if you open your settings.xml you will see a tag mentioning.

```
<repositories>
   ........
</repositories>
```

The default location is the .m2 directory in the Users directory on Windows.